# 'realm/util/bind_ptr.hpp' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, realm

I keep getting ***'realm/util/bind_ptr.hpp' file not found*** when I Build my project

[image: error message]

Cocoapods 1.1.1
Realm version 0.92.3
X-Code 8
Swift 3

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That Realm version sounds super old. Aren't they are like 2.6?

Comment: (Willow from Realm here) As @EpicPandaForce suggested, I would recommend that you update to the latest version of Realm and try again. It's possible that the version of Realm you're currently using just isn't compatible with the versions of Xcode and Swift you're using.